# FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage) does not work in my application flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification

I have integrated FCM into my application Flutter. I manage to receive notifications but when I click on an application I get no results.

I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: How do you implement the _handleMessage function? And when you send the notifications do you implement this on firebase?   'click_action':'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
'status': 'done',

Comment: please share your implementation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.